# Importing Python files based on radio input

Tags: python, nicegui

I want to import certain files based on input from the user using some sort of selection (I am using a radio button). I am having trouble getting the updated selection from the user to send to check the input and go to the desired page for the selection while importing the desired classes from another Python file in the process.

For example, suppose from another file `scriptA.py`, I have the class:

```
class A:
   def __init__(self, a):
      self.a = a
```

and from `scriptB.py` I have the class

```
class B:
   def __init__(self, b):
      self.b = b
```

In my app script `app.py`, I want to obtain the input for the user and given the input, go to the desired page and importing the class for the input:

```
class ImportSelection:
   def __init__(self, selection = None):
      self.selection = selection

importselection = ImportSelection()
ui.radio(['A', 'B']).bind_value(importselection, 'selection')

@ui.page('/A')
def page_A():
   from scriptA import A
   # do stuff

@ui.page('/B'):
def page_B():
   from scriptB import B
   # do stuff


if importselection.selection == 'A':
   ui.link("/A", page_A)
elif importselection.selection == 'B':
   ui.link("/B", page_B)

ui.run()
```

I am having trouble getting the user input to then go to the page. How should I refactor this code to do this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your app code:

1. Why your links are not created: NiceGUI works based on callbacks so
   code outside of a callback only happens once. When the code
   initially runs, `importselection.selection` is `None` and the links
   are not created.
2. The navigation: `ui.link` created HTML links and
   does not navigate. You need `ui.open`
3. Binding to the radio buttons:
   You need to create a callback that will happen when the value of the
   radio selection changes. This is done by setting `on_change` in the
   `radio` element.

Here is a working example (that requires your scriptA.py and scriptB.py to exist):

```py
from nicegui import ui


@ui.page('/A')
def page_A():
    from scriptA import A
    ui.link('back', '/')


@ui.page('/B')
def page_B():
    from scriptB import B
    ui.link('back', '/')


routing_map = {
    'A': page_A,
    'B': page_B,
}
ui.radio(
    list(routing_map.keys()), 
    on_change=lambda e: ui.open(routing_map[e.value])
)

ui.run()
```

Comment: Awesome answer! I will give this a try, thank you! So it seems you embed the link into the radio selection?